# React Vis x can't be a string

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I am using React Vis to create a simple Graph. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../../node_modules/react-vis/dist/style.css';
import {XYPlot, VerticalBarSeries} from 'react-vis';

const myData = [
  {x: 'A', y: 10},
  {x: 'B', y: 5},
  {x: 'C', y: 15}
]


export const Chart = () => {
  return (
      <XYPlot height={500} width={500}>
        <VerticalBarSeries data={myData} />
      </XYPlot>
  )
};

export default Chart;
```

I receive this error message:
`` Received NaN for the `x` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string." ``

When I change the x values in myData to ints, it works, but I need them as strings. The documentation clearly states that this should work:
[image]

Comment: For string x values you must specify the `xType = "ordinal"` props for the `XYPlot` component.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you so much! Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

For the x value to be a string you need to add `xType='ordinal'` to the `XYPlot` as following:

```
export const Chart = () => {
  return (
      <XYPlot height={500} width={500} xType='ordinal'>
        <VerticalBarSeries data={myData} />
      </XYPlot>
  )
};
```

Now it should work for you.